# What's a Tricky Word™?

Tags: word, word-property

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a **Tricky Word™**. Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Tricky Words | Not Tricky Words |
| --- | --- |
| RHYTHM | ELEPHANT |
| GIRL | BOOK |
| GYM | STUFFED |
| STRENGTH | WEAKNESS |
| TWELFTH | ELEVENTH |
| MONTHLY | YEARLY |
| SPLOTCH | ACCIDENT |
| LENGTH | HEIGHT |
| STRETCH | EXAMPLE |
| SKETCH | SHOELACES |
| SUN | MOON |
| HAPPY | EPIC |

Hints, added 1 hour later:

> Tricky is also a **Tricky Word™**.

> There are two types of **Tricky Words™**, a **no V Tricky Word™** and a **one V Tricky Word™**

> And in the table there are only two **no V Tricky Word™**.

<sub>This continues the [What is a Word/Phrase](/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aq) series started by [JLee](/u/463).</sub>

Comment: You have HAPPY listed as both tricky and not tricky

Comment: @Herb Good catch, what a blunder

Comment: Added a hint one hour after posting the question.

Comment: Hello U12-Forward. Amazingly there is a 10 letter long Country name with thr Tricky property.

Comment: @DrD Yeap! I know which one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Tricky Word is

> a word which has at most one vowel (with Y not being counted as a vowel).

The hint

> that there are only two "no V Tricky Words" refers to the first two words, RHYTHM and GYM, which have no vowels.

The connection with the title is

> presumably just that tricky itself is a Tricky Word.

Comment: You've got it spot on, congratulations!